# Store form values in a table on multiple requests

Tags: php, memory, dynamic

Here I have an HTML form that stores stores submitted data in a table.

```
<label> ID: </label><input type="text" name="id"/>
<label>Name :</label><textarea name='Name'></textarea>
<label>Value :</label><br /><input type="text" name="Value"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=" submit "/>
```

Next time I submit the form, the table refreshes and stores the new values. Instead I need it to add new rows to table and store all previous data I submit during the session. How do I add the new rows without using a data base?

```
<?php
session_start();
echo  "<table> 
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  echo "
  <tr> 
  <td>".$_POST['id']."</td>
  <td>".$_POST['Name']."</td>
  <td>".$_POST['Value']."</td>
  </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo  "<table> 
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  $_SESSION['posts'][] = $_POST;
  foreach ($_SESSION['posts'] as $post)
    echo "<tr>
            <td>{$post['id']}</td>
            <td>{$post['Name']}</td>
            <td>{$post['Value']}</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

or if you want it all in one page:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo  "<table> 
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  $_SESSION['posts'][] = $_POST;
  foreach ($_SESSION['posts'] as $post)
    echo "<tr>
            <td>{$post['id']}</td>
            <td>{$post['Name']}</td>
            <td>{$post['Value']}</td>
        </tr>";
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
<label> ID: </label><input type="text" name="id"/><br>
<label>Name :</label><textarea name='Name'></textarea><br>
<label>Value :</label><br /><input type="text" name="Value"/><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=" submit "/><br>
```